# creating a list in html using jQuery append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I've been staring at this code for hours now, any input appreciated.

I want to create a list in a HTML file from an array of objects using jquery append, but it justs stays blank.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list">
    </div>

    <div id="template">
      <div class="info">
        <a class="url"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
function update(events) {
    var eventList = $('#list');
    eventList.empty();
    events.forEach(
        function(_event) {
            var eventsHtml = $('#template .info').clone();
            eventsHtml.find('.url').text(_event.title)
                                   .attr('href', _event.url);              
            eventList.append(eventsHtml);
        });
}
var events = [{title:'fu',url:'bar'}, {title:'bar',url:'fu'}];
update(events);
```

Comment: You are embedding your script before `#list` exists ... place script behind it, or use `$(function() { ... })` to run code when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the JS code you show is contained in test.js, either move this line:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

...to the end of the body (just before the closing `</body>` tag), or wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` handler.

The way you currently have it, this line:

```
var eventList = $('#list')
```

...doesn't find the `'#list'` element because the script runs before the element is parsed. Same problem with finding `'#template .info'`.

You could wrap *all* of the code in a ready handler, or if you need to be able to call the `update()` function from elsewhere just wrap the initial call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var events = [{title:'fu',url:'bar'}, {title:'bar',url:'fu'}];
    update(events);
});
```

Comment: ARGH! Of course.. Thank you very much, now I can go on with my life.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var events = [{title:'fu',url:'bar'}, {title:'bar',url:'fu'}];
   var eventList = $('#list');
   eventList.empty();
   events.forEach(
     function(_event) {
        var eventsHtml = $('#template .info').clone();
        eventsHtml.find('.url').text(_event.title)
                               .attr('href', _event.url);              
        eventList.append(eventsHtml);
     });
  });
```